# Putting status bar information into a MessageBox popup in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So i'm comletely new to WPF and C# and have been tasked to take the existing information we have in a status bar of our MainWindow.xaml and put it in a popup, like a MessageBox.  I'm not really sure how to do that as I can see some of the code that generates the text, and the values for the progress bar in code, but I don't see how those individual methods get bound to the .xaml file.  Here's what's in the current xaml.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<StatusBar Width="Auto" MaxHeight="50" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="300"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Name="tbxProgressText" Text="{Binding Path=ProgressText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Name="tbxProgressText2" Text="{Binding Path=ProgressText2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
    <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
        <ProgressBar Width="300" Height="18" Name="ProgressBar" 
                     Value="{Binding Path=PbarValue, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     Minimum="{Binding Min}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Comment: They should have tasked you to read through all the [introductory material on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) first...

Comment: A TextBlock with a TwoWay binding??? That's new...

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this (untested and unstyled):

```
<Popup Width="Auto" MaxHeight="50" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsOpen="true">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="tbxProgressText" Text="{Binding Path=ProgressText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBlock Name="tbxProgressText2" Text="{Binding Path=ProgressText2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ProgressBar Width="300" Height="18" Name="ProgressBar" 
                 Value="{Binding Path=PbarValue, Mode=OneWay}" 
                 Minimum="{Binding Min}" Maximum="{Binding Maximum}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

This popup will be always open because of the property IsOpen="true" and it will be placed where the statusbar is placed in the current application. You could start by fixing those things and then try to add some styles to the content of the popup.
Hope it helps!